# neo4j 2.2.0 load csv and split function

Tags: neo4j

I have a file for nodes that has multiple values in columns `en` and `el`. For some nodes there might be no values, eg the id 1 has no values in column `el`.

```
id;en;el
1;"United States of America;USA;U.S.A.";
2;"Greece;Hellas;Hellenic Republic";"Ελλάδα;Ελλάς;Ελληνική Δημοκρατία"
```

Using neo4j version 2.1.5 I was able to import this nodes with the following command:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///home/aris/tmp/nodes.csv" as node FIELDTERMINATOR ';' CREATE(:Location {id: node.id, en: split(node.en, ";"), el: split(node.el, ";")});
```

Using neo4j version 2.2.0-M02 I get the following error:

```
String didn't extract value for Mark[line:2, from:77, to:77]. For values which are optional please use tryExtract method instead
```

Obviously the lack of values in `el` column produces the error. I tried to find about `tryExtract` method with no luck. How can I import this data?

Comment: I consider this being a regression bug, please file a github issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/3824#issuecomment-70478845 "This has been fixed after M02, and will be included in the next release"